# Mvc - store a list in session and then retrieve its value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I'm trying to make a simple online magazine and I got to the part where when the user clicks addtoCart button

My model Cart holds two properties - product and Quantity

```
public class Cart
{

 public ProductLanguages Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

So in my basketViewModel (class) inside my AddProductToCart method I add the product, the details for which I get from database in property of List.

So I can't figure out this issue: Somewhere in the control I should save this list in a Session and if the user adds more products the next time I should get the list from this session. If someone can give me an example of controler with an index action that can do this I would be really thankful.

```
public class BasketViewModel
    {

        private readonly IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository;
        public List<Cart> listProductsinBasket { get; set; }
        public BasketViewModel() : this(new ProductLanguagesRepository())
        {

        }



    public BasketViewModel(IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository)
    {
        this.prodlanRepository = prodlanRepository;
    }
    public void AddProductToCart(int id,int quantity)
    {
        ProductLanguages nwProduct = prodlanRepository.GetProductDetails(id);
        if (nwProduct != null)
        {
            Cart cr = new Cart();
            cr.Product = nwProduct;
            cr.Quantity = quantity;
            listProductsinBasket.Add(cr);

        }
```

Comment: Don't put repositories inside your viewModel - do it inside your controller. Your viewmodel should only have "listProductsinBasket". @KindzaDza is right regarding the session and you should mark his/her answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Store:**

```
HttpContext.Session["list"] = new List<object> { new object(), new object() };
```

**Retrieve:**

```
var list = HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] as List<object>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - but I have another problem -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596123/why-my-session-in-the-view-control-is-null

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bad practice and has possibly both security and performance impact. Why don't you store in the session only basket id and retrieve related items in the controller?