# Why my session in the view control is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I'm trying to make a simple online magazine and I get to the part where when the user clicks `addtoCart` button

My model Cart holds two properties - Product and Quantity

```
public class Cart
{

 public ProductLanguages Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

So in my `basketViewModel` in my `AddProductToCart` method, I add the product with details I get from database in property of type List. Then I save this list in a session.
And if, for example, the user clicks 'continue to shop' button and returns to index page -  next time when he presses 'addtocart' for the new product as you see I make this check

```
lstCarts = (List<Cart>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        if (lstCarts==null)
        {
           lstCarts = new List<Cart>();
        }
```

First, I try to get the list from session so i can get previously saved products.
But my session is always null so i always lose my previously purchased products. The curious thing is that I'm sure that I saved the list of products in this line

```
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = lstCarts;
```

Here is my viewmodel

```
 public class BasketViewModel
    {
    private readonly IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository;
    public List<Cart> lstCarts { get; set; }
    public BasketViewModel() : this(new ProductLanguagesRepository())
    {

    }

    public BasketViewModel(IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository)
    {
        this.prodlanRepository = prodlanRepository;
    }
    public void CreateCart(int id,int quantity)
    {
        lstCarts = (List<Cart>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        if (lstCarts==null)
        {
           lstCarts = new List<Cart>();
        }
        ProductLanguages nwProduct = prodlanRepository.GetProductDetails(id);
        if (nwProduct != null)
        {
            Cart cr = new Cart();
            cr.Product = nwProduct;
            cr.Quantity = quantity;
            lstCarts.Add(cr);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = lstCarts;
        }
    }      
}
```

And my Controller

```
 public class BasketManagementController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index(int id, int quantity)
            {
                BasketViewModel vm = new BasketViewModel();
                vm.CreateCart(id, quantity);
                return View(vm);
            }
     }
```

Comment: Could the application pool be recycled between the time you stored the value in the session and the time you try to read it? For example if you recompile your application that's what will happen.

Comment: No when the user likes some product and clicks 'addoptoduct' this product is stored i list and then that list in session - and then if he presses 'continue to shop' - he is redirected to index page with all products and this Session is lost

Comment: What happens if you move the line `HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = lstCarts;` out of the if-clause, i.e. set it regardless of if it changed?

Comment: Your code should work.  Nothing appears to be wrong with it.  Have you verified that you have SessionState enabled?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on: HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = lstCarts; and check if it is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the concepts wrong:

*The view model is for get and set properties object

*The controller is for operations with the view model objects

Please try like this bellow

```
//VIEW MODEL

   public class BasketViewModel{
    public List<Cart> lstCarts { get; set; }    
   }

//CONTROLLER


         public class BasketManagementController : Controller
        {

        private IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository;

        public BasketManagementController(IProductLanguagesRepository prodlanRepository){

            this.prodlanRepository = prodlanRepository;

        } 

            public ActionResult Index(int id, int quantity)
             {
                CreateCart(id, quantity);
                BasketViewModel vm = new BasketViewModel();
                return View(vm);
             }

             public void CreateCart(int id,int quantity)
            {
                lstCarts = (List<Cart>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
                if (lstCarts==null)
                {
                   lstCarts = new List<Cart>();
                }
                ProductLanguages nwProduct = prodlanRepository.GetProductDetails(id);
                if (nwProduct != null)
                {
                    Cart cr = new Cart();
                    cr.Product = nwProduct;
                    cr.Quantity = quantity;
                    lstCarts.Add(cr);
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = lstCarts;
                }
            } 


             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen certain behavior.
May be you problem with the line

`ProductLanguages nwProduct = prodlanRepository.GetProductDetails(id);`

There may some exception with GetProductDetails(id)

Check out that.